# My app outputs [object Object] in place of a text string - how to fix please?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnr26.jpg)I want to pull data from API pages like this one: https://api.discogs.com/releases/249504

You can see it contains, for instance...

```
"labels": [{"name": "RCA", "entity_type": "1", "catno": "PB 41447"
```

I want to read     labels.name and     labels.catno into my script in order to output this data as .csv

I tried changing      labels to     labels.name but that didn't work and just created a serious error.

In my main     scripts.js file I have...

```
  const id = data.id;
  const artist = data.artists[0].name;
  var title = data.title;
  var formats = data.formats;
  var labels = data.labels;
  var country = data.country;
  if (country == "") country = "Unknown";
  var released = data.released_formatted;
  if (typeof released == 'undefined') released = "Unknown";
  const genres = data.genres[0];
  var styles = data.styles;
  if (typeof styles == 'undefined') styles = "None";
  let tracklist =''; //sets tracklist to an empty string
```

[...]

```
            const id = data.id;
            const artist = data.artists[0].name;
            var title = data.title;
            var formats = data.formats;
            var labels = data.labels;
            var country = data.country;
            if (country == "") country = "Unknown";
            var released = data.released_formatted;
            if (typeof released == 'undefined') released = "Unknown";
            const genres = data.genres[0];
            var styles = data.styles;
            if (typeof styles == 'undefined') styles = "None";
            let tracklist =''; //sets tracklist to an empty string
```

...but in my     csv.js file I also have...

```
const id = data.id
const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : []
const title = data.title || []
const formats = data.formats || []
const labels = data.labels || []
        console.log(labels);
const country = data.country || 'Unknown'
const released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown'
const genres = data.genres || []
const styles = data.styles || []
const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : []
```

I'm not sure why what is a variable in one file is a constant in another; perhaps that needs fixing.

I want one column in my csv file to give labels.name and one to give labels.catno.

Comment: If you are seeing [Object object] it is because you are not pulling the key for the value you think you are pulling. Where is it occurring?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting it in the .csv file that my app creates. For instance..

    1,The Persuader,Stockholm,[object Object],Sweden,Mar 1999,"Electronic","Deep House","Östermalm,Vasastaden,Kungsholmen,Södermalm,Norrmalm,Gamla Stan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that your shown 'labels' is not an object. Its an array of objects. And reading this like `labels.name` and `labels.catno` will not work.

```
"labels": [{"name": "RCA", "entity_type": "1", "catno": "PB 41447" ...
          ^ Array
```

changing this into an object like

```
"labels": {"name": "RCA", "entity_type": "1", "catno": "PB 41447" ...
```

or using `labels[0].name` and `labels[0].catno` should solve your problem.